# How to add a component to existing LibreOffice?

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, libreoffice

Initially I didn't think I would need Impress Presentation, so through a custom installation I left it out. Of course, now I could use it ;) Go figure! Can I do this? I am using Ubuntu Studio 16.04 (XFCE)

Answer (score 5):

This impressive command should satisfy your hunger:

```
sudo apt install libreoffice-impress
```

Comment: I'm amazed at the wording of both: question and answer.  Made my U&L day.